# Copy file from repository A to repository B, git

Tags: git

I need to copy files from repository A to other repository with all the history of the commits ofcourse.

I check this way:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <FILE_NAME>
git remote set-url <NEW URL>
git push origin <branch_name>
```

There is some better way for doing this?